# HSQLDB : Get table indices

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb, querying

I need a way to find out if a present table in HSQLDB has any indices, and if so, fetch their detailed information (column_name, type, isPrimary ...etc)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Try looking up 'Metadata' in the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_INDEXINFO
```

More details about the system views can be found in the manual: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema